# How to Erase or Clear a Vector of Structure Datatype

Tags: c++, vector, structure, c++03

Let define a Structure

```
struct data{
 int a, b;
};
```

and

```
vector<data>v
```

Now my Question is how to Clear / Erase this Vector / Vector's Element in C++ ( It will be better for If you post an answer for old version of C++ Compiler Like C ++ 4.3.2 / C++ [Not C ++ 11/14] )

Comment: Doesn't [`v.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) work for you??

Comment: do you want to delete all of the data structures entirely, or set their data equal to 0?

Comment: I have tried v.clear().. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @ssavi What do you mean with "It doesn't work"? Do you think still being able to access the elements after `vector::clear` means that it is not cleared? That would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To delete all of the elements ( call destructors, declare that you no longer plan to use that space... the actual vector implementation decides when to release that space but you don't have to worry about that ):

`v.clear();`

ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

<s>Note: if you want to immediately release the memory in the vector, use `v.resize(0);`</s>

To set all of the values of your structures to 0 the quick and dirty (but not necessarily pretty or advisable) way is: `memset( v.data(), 0, sizeof(data) * v.size() );`

Comment: *"Note: if you want to immediately release the memory in the vector, use v.resize(0);"* Nope, same problem as with `clear`. May I recommend a [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)?

Comment: @BaummitAugen interesting, thanks. I was under the impression that resize actually changed the capacity and released resources. my mistake.

Comment: If you want to eliminate excess memory here are two ways; The C++03 way: `v.swap(std::vector<T>(v));` and the C++11 way: `v.shrink_to_fit();`.